# How can I improve the ramda code I have written?

Tags: ramda.js

I am new to ramda.js, I have written the following code which checks if the value doesn't already end with the suffix in the provided list, it adds "px" suffix

```
function addSuffix(value, suffix = 'px', test = ['px', 'pt', '%']) {
  return compose(
    concat(value),
    ifElse(anyPass(map(endsWith, test)), () => '', () => suffix)
  )(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the first suggestion I'd make is to avoid working with default parameters. They usually don't play well with curried functions.

You can write a function that returns a function to checks whether a string ends up with a given list of suffixes:

```js
const hasSuffixFn = compose(anyPass, map(endsWith));
const hasSuffix = hasSuffixFn(['px', 'pt', '%']);

hasSuffix('foo'); // false
hasSuffix('1px'); // true
```

Then you can have a function that takes a list of suffixes and a suffix and returns a function that will append that suffix if it isn't present already:

```js
const addSuffix = (suffixes, suffix) => unless(hasSuffix(suffixes), flip(concat)(suffix));

const addPx = addSuffix(['px', 'pt', '%'], 'px');
addPx('10'); // '10px'
addPx('10px'); // '10px'
addPx('10pt'); // '10pt'
```

Please note that you could rewrite `addSuffix` in a [pointfree](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/06/21/thinking-in-ramda-pointfree-style/) style with `useWith`:

```js
const addSuffix = useWith(unless, [hasSuffix, flip(concat)]);
```

**Putting it altogether**

```js
const hasSuffix = compose(anyPass, map(endsWith));
const addSuffix = (suffixes, suffix) => unless(hasSuffix(suffixes), flip(concat)(suffix));
const addPx = addSuffix(['px', 'pt', '%'], 'px');

console.log(addPx('10'));
console.log(addPx('10px'));
console.log(addPx('10pt'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {anyPass, endsWith, unless, flip, concat, compose, map} = R;</script>
```

---

**APPENDIX**

*Why not using default parameters?*

I don't know if using default parameters is a recommend practice in functional programming but I have realised that they usually get in the way when you need to partially apply a function.

Take a look at this:

Here we have a function that adds three numbers:

```js
const foo = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;
foo(10, 20, 30); // 60
```

We can curry this and start partially applying that function:

```js
const foo_curried = curry(foo);
foo_curried(10, 20, 30); // 60
foo_curried(10, 20)(30); // 60
foo_curried(10)(20, 30); // 60
foo_curried(10)(20)(30); // 60
```

Let's write a similar function but with default parameters. This works as expected:

```js
const bar = (a=10, b=20, c=30) => a + b + c;
bar();              // 60
bar(110);           // 160
bar(110, 220);      // 360
bar(110, 220, 330); // 660
```

However if you want to curry this and partially apply it, then you'll get errors:

```js
const bar_curried = curry(bar);
bar_curried();              // 60
bar_curried(110);           // 160
bar_curried(110)(220, 330); // Error!
```

Why? A curried function waits until you've provided all its arguments. Until then it keeps returning a function that accept the remaining arguments. However if you partially apply a function that has default parameters then you can't really predict what the curried function will return: the final result or a function that accepts the remaining argument?

In the last example, `bar_curried(110)` returns the result directly, i.e. `110 + 20 + 30` and the error arises when you try to invoke a number as if it was a function.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But I want the checklist ['px', 'pt', 'px'] to be dynamic. It will come as a function argument. If you look at my original code I was doing map and ifElse to achieve it.

Comment: Indeed. We can apply the same principles though. I'll update

Comment: I saw the question as I got on my bus this morning, and composed an answer in my head, got to work and was about to type it up when I saw that you had written almost exactly the same thing, even down to the note about `useWith`!  An important change you coded but didn't mention is to switch from `ifElse` to the less clunky `unless`; this often makes code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet. I just added an appendix about default parameters in curried functions. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @customcommander: I agree entirely.  Because default parameters do not contribute to the function's arity they are very hard to combine with currying or any other sort of partial application.  I have found one place, though, where they are very useful: writing recursive functions without the need of helper functions.  I don't tend to mix recursion with partial application, so that is not a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

you could also avoid passing the list of suffixes, since it looks to be redundant... just make sure that the given `value` doesn't end with a digit:

```js
const ensureSuffix = R.curry((suffix, value) =>
  R.unless(R.test(/\D$/), v => `${v}${suffix}`, value),
);

const addPx = ensureSuffix('px');

console.log(addPx(15));
console.log(addPx('15pt'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the idea with the suffix list is to avoid adding a css unit eg px where one exists already. So for example `addPx('15pt')` should return the value as is.

Comment: In which case I think your algorithm makes a wrong assumption: units are not replaceable, `15pt` is very different from `15px`... I think you are looking for a simple `safe add unit`, which adds a unit if not present. updated my answer.